# PHP: Mail multiple attachments headers

Tags: php, email, header, attachment

I'm trying to e-mail with multiple attachments within the mail. So far i succeeded to mail with one attachment, but I can't figure out how to send multiple files in one e-mail.

```
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$bericht = $this -> _message;
$this -> _headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$this -> _headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="'. $uid .'"' . PHP_EOL;
$this -> _message = '--' . $uid . PHP_EOL;
$this -> _message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$this -> _message .= '--' . $uid . PHP_EOL;
$this -> _message .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
$this -> _message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$this -> _message .= $bericht . PHP_EOL;
$this -> _message .= '--' . $uid . PHP_EOL;

foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
    if(is_file($attachment) && is_readable($attachment)) {
        $handle = fopen($attachment, 'r');
        $content = fread($handle, filesize($attachment));
        fclose($handle);
        $this -> _message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; name="' .
                              basename($attachment) . '"' . PHP_EOL;
        $this -> _message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . PHP_EOL;
        $this -> _message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        $this -> _message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content)) . PHP_EOL;
        $this -> _message .= '--' . $uid . '--' . PHP_EOL;
    }    
}
```

Does anybody know's what i'm doing wrong? :)

It does send a mail with only one attachment. If i select two, then only one will be send. I don't want to use a libary because of the size of the website.

Comment: use PHPMailer class it's much simpler http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: What happens when you try to send two attachments? Does the code fail? Does the email get sent, but never arrive? Does only one attachment come through?

Comment: I agree with @Waygood. You're killing yourself here. I'm going to throw my hat in Swiftmailer's corner: http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: It does send a mail with only one attachment. If I select two, then only one will be send. I don't want to use a libary because of the size of the website. :)